# Rails prepend_view_paths not overriding default view path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I am working on re-templating an admin portion of an app that requires rendering different views instead of the old styles. With the below, `view_paths` shows that the path is prepended, but still rendering the old views.

```
# View folder structure
# /app
# --/views
# ----/admin
# ------/dashboard
# --------show.html.erb
# ----/admin_v2
# ------/dashboard
# --------show.html.erb

# routes.rb
constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
    scope module: 'admin', as: 'admin' do
        root to: 'dashboard#show'
    end
end

# AdminController
class AdminController < ApplicationController
    prepend_view_paths "#{Rails.root}/app/views/admin_v2"
end

# Admin::DashboardController
class Admin::DashboardController < AdminController
    def show
    end
end
```

I have moved a few things around, trying to poke holes in it, but my only guess is that it has something to do with the way my routes are structured.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Does `prepend_view_paths 'views/admin_v2'` work?

Comment: Negative on both `'views/admin_v2'` and `"#{Rails.root}/app/views/admin_v2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out myself.

It has to do with the route scope. Basically it was adding an admin prefix to my `lookup_context`.

By changing my folder structure to take this into account, like below, I was able to get everything working.

```
# View folder structure
# /app
# --/views
# ----/admin
# ------/dashboard
# --------show.html.erb
# ----/admin_v2
# ------/admin
# --------/dashboard
# ----------show.html.erb
```